# Arraylist of Class klazz (Reflection Api)

Tags: java, generics, reflection, arraylist

I need to create a new ArrayList of the Class klazz to use it in a method. I have:

```
Class klazz= Integer.class // for example purposes
method( new <?????> ArrayList() );
```

I am lost here could you help out? 
(it seems as it could be done in one line of code, or am i complete wrong about this?)

I need it because it feeds a method of http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/ and it will define the output of other methods. they are now returning Object and that is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a generic method like this one:

```
public <E> ArrayList<E> getArrayListOf(Class<E> clazz) {
    return new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

The type of the generated List will be `List<? extends YourClass>` or `List<YourClass>` if YourClass is final.

Comment: `clazz` is not used and is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
method(new ArrayList());
```

Generics are a compile time feature which is erased at runtime.

Comment: the "method" method belongs to http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/ and it will later define the output of other methods. That's why i asked.

Comment: @lrn2java If you don't know the type at compile time, it doesn't matter.  Use anything which compiles.